# Force suspend when closing lid

Tags: suspend

Some oppened apps (such as teamviewer or chrome when on an teleconference website) seems to **prevent** my laptop **from going to sleep** when I close the lid.

How to force laptop to go to sleep(=suspend) when I close the lid ?

ENV: ubuntu 20.04 on a thinkpad t14s

Comment: This is an interesting problem. What would motivate you to want your laptop to suspend in the middle of a teleconference?

Comment: No matter whatever softwares is running, when I close my lid and throw my laptop in my backpack, I want it suspended not to get hot. Closing all my. apps beforehand is tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block`

will list you all the apps that will prevent suspend/hibernation.

The only way to "force" a suspend will be to write a script that will "kill" these apps.

In xfce that would include the xfce4-power-manager who is responsible for checking if someone inhibits - so there should be exceptions from the rule.

The answer of the call above will provide you with the app name and its pid.
If killing an app this way is a good idea was not asked by the OP.

You'd have to connect that script to the "lidClose" acpi call or create a systemd service that will be executed before suspend:

```
[Unit]
Before=suspend.target
[Service]
Type=simple
StandardOutput=syslog
ExecStart= yourScriptHere
[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not work:
google-chrome, when in my visioconfernece website (https://kmeet.infomaniak.com/) is blocking susped but does not show up in `systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block`

Comment: Edit: actually a new line DOES appear in this command output, but it's PID is not as expected, it's the one from "gnome-session-binary", killing it results in a chrome crash :/

Comment: what about `killall "google-chrome"` ? It'll sandbox your apps, so you won't see them process wise

Comment: 1. I don't want to kill chrome if it's not runnig any sleep blocking 
2. "systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block" dives out a generic gnome PID with no way to know it's due to chrome.
3. this program seems to be able to list chrome blocking by it's appID https://pypi.org/project/list-session-inhibitors/
4. now I just have to find a way to kill an app knowing only it's app ID, which is probably doable, will try when I have time.

Comment: Report back. I'd be interested in your solution

Comment: Correct. This will certainly work. But I didn't recommend it, because this bypasses any "driver cleanups" systemd/pm-suspend will do. Try this with a NVIDIA card and it won't come back on resume